# Mongodb does not save a document

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to store some data from an HTML formulary. I send the data using the HTTP POST method and I received them using Express framework in Node.js. The data arrives and it seems to work, but when I try to store them into MongoDB using Mongoose, the database is created but no data is stored when I execute DB.sis_dictionary.find()

I've tried to build different types of schemas and models, but none seems to work. And I get no error from Node.js, it seems to be working, but the MongoDB database does not store anything.

```
const Mongoose = require('mongoose');
Mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/sis_dictionary', {useNewUrlParser: true});
const Schema = Mongoose.Schema;
const wordSchema = new Schema({
  word: String
})
const Word = Mongoose.model('Word', wordSchema);

app.post('/saveWord', (req, res) => {
    var word = new Word({word: String(req.body)});
    word.save(function(err){
      if(err) {
        return console.error(err);
      } else {
        console.log("STATUS: WORKING");
      }
    })
    console.log(req.body);
})

server.listen(3000);

console.log("SERVER STARTUP SUCCESS");
```

In the console, I get the message: "STATUS: WORKING".

Comment: What do you have in `req.body` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your database URL, `mongodb://localhost:27017/sis_dictionary`, `sis_dictionary` is the database name.

And according to your `mongoose` model, `Word` is your collection name.

When you save a document, it saves under a collection. So you have to make a query under the collections.

So when you try to get data using `DB.sis_dictionary.find()`, definitely it won't work.

Your query should be like `db.collection.find()`

Use the following query,

```
use sis_dictionary
db.words.find()
// for better view
db.words.find().pretty()
```

For more please check the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/).

Answer (score 1):

`sis_ditionary` is your DB name and `Words` should be your collection name. As mongoose automatically creates a plural name for collection from a model if model name not specified when creating from a schema

`db.collection.find()` is a command to find a collection data when using mongo-shell. Run below command to get data:

- `use sis_dictionary`
- `db.Words.find()`

  To beautify result use pretty method

  `db.Words.find().pretty()`

First command will select DB and second command list collection data.

So when you execute `db.sis_dictionary.find()` it won't work because sis_dictinary is your DB name.

Nodejs way with 'mongoose'

```
//Model.find({});
  Word.find({});
```

Also, check this line `var word = new Word({word: String(req.body)});`
What does req.body have? If req.body is `{word:"example word"}` then you directly pass req.body to modal constructor ie `new Word(req.body)`;

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody. You were all right, it was a problem related to my collections names. db.words.find().pretty() worked perfectly!The problem is solved.